# Reading an Image Pixel by Pixel

Tags: android

Is there anyway I can read pixel by pixel a jpeg without taking the whole Image into memory?
I have been searching this for a long time.Thanking you in advance for your valuable advice.

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I am writing a program to convert a large image into b/w(and similar operations),so I want to convert an image (of size say 16MB) into b/w..I cant read the entire image into memory as android memory is limited.So all I can do is to load the image Pixel by Pixel and manipulate those pixels and add the pixels to a new File

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because jpeg image data isn't written pixel by pixel in the jpeg file format. But as far as I remember, jpeg encodes blocks of 8x8 pixels, so you might hold on to that...

Comment: Ok,In that case Can I retrieve that 8x8 array of pixels,(IMP: with out loading the whole image into memory)

Comment: I really have no idea whether this is possible, but you might try it out... Sorry I cannot give you more suggestions, it was just an idea.